# How to allow users to enter a custom email address into the Alert Me dialog?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Title says it.  I have a Sharepoint 2010 instance that's for an intranet and profiles are managed by Active Directory.  Because of this, users who hit Alert Me have their email prepopulated in the form and are not allowed to change it.  I want to let them put in whatever email they want to be notified at instead.  Is there a way to do this?

*** UPDATE ***
Not really a duplicate of the other question, because I'm not talking about external users (all the users are actually my AD users), but I guess I should have elaborated more.

So in our organization, the user logins are not the same as the email address, because we use organizational mailboxes that are shared based on security group in AD.

So, for example, the user john.doe might be a member of the HR department's New Hire section, so he'd share a HR_NewHire@mycompany.com email with others on his team.

Sharepoint sees his email as john.doe@mycompany.com, though, and he can't change that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To: Send the Alert Emails to External Email Addresses?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/how-to-send-the-alert-emails-to-external-email-addresses)

Answer (score 1):

This is already discussed here :- [How To: Send the Alert Emails to External Email Addresses?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32796/how-to-send-the-alert-emails-to-external-email-addresses)

The question contains two approaches to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint intentionally keeps (non-administrator) users from setting up alerts for other users. Therefore, out of the box, there's no way for a general user to select other AD addresses to send alerts to. However, there are 3rd party alert tools that can do this. I use InfoWise Smart Alert Pro. There are a number of more complicated options for customizing the alert, as compared to the out-of-the-box alert settings, but our users have been able to figure it out.